# <input type="date" name="purchasedDate" id="purchasedDate"> not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

I am getting issue with the input tag. It works fine in all major browsers except Internet Explorer.

My version of IE is 8.

```
<input type="date" name="purchasedDate" id="purchasedDate">
```

I have tried some scripts too like polyfills but still the issue is not solved.

Comment: "My version of IE is 8." — Your version of IE is ancient … and is [three days away from never getting another security update](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support).

Comment: "I  have tried some scripts too like polyfills" — We can't tell why your JavaScript doesn't work without seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hi Meeti,**

IE do not supports most of the features like this. So to solve this you have to include scripts to do that.

**Sample Script**

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
    nope: "js/jquery-ui.custom.js",
    callback: function() {
      $("input[type=date]").datepicker();
    }
});
```

I hope this will work for u.

Comment: Thanks Rish... Now it is working,,

Answer (score 0):

The element `<input type="date" />` is [**not supported**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) in IE 8. **Period.**

**Solution:**

1. Replace `date` with `text`.
2. Use a [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) / [JavaScript](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCalendar/) Date Picker.

> ***Note:*** You can't have a truck running with the engines of Ferrari.